# Read Google Sheets from app using API for personal account

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-account

I've developing an app to parse Google Sheets. So I need a way users can share their Google Sheets with my account. I can use a service account and it works fine, but the problem is a service account has an ugly name. And when I share the sheet with my main account, the service account can't see it.

Is there some way to share a Google Sheets spreadsheet with my main (personal) account and let the service account see this? Or maybe there is some way to get my main account credentials keys like for the service one.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `So I want to ask if there some way to share google sheet with my main (presonal) account and let service account see this. Or my be there is some way to get my main account credentials keys like for the service one.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike I tried to fix the typos

Comment: @Mark Thank you for your support. But. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still imagine the situation of `Is there some way to share a Google Sheets spreadsheet with my main (personal) account and let the service account see this?`.  
 But, I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. In order to imagine various situations in English, I think that I have to study more.

Comment: @Tanaike I'm sure that my English is too bad. Sorry for this. I will try to paraphrase.

Case 1: I share google sheet with service account. 
result: Service account have access to this google sheet.
Case 2:  I share google sheet with my google account. 
result: Service account do not have access to this google sheet.

I need:  I share google sheet with my google account. 
result: Service account have access to this google sheet.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your reply, in your situation, is this document of "[Service account impersonation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-overview#impersonation)
" useful? If I misunderstood your reply, I apologize, again.